# Name for a constrained Poisson-like bridge process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I have a sequence $t_i$ for $i=0,2,\cdots,n$ of integer jump times with $t_0=0$ and $t_n=n$ such that the waiting time $t_{i+1}-t_i$ has distribution density $f_i(t)$. So it's kind of like a Poisson process with a rate that depends on time and number of jumps so far, in addition to making a bridge between 0 and $n$ jumps. Is there a proper name for such a process? Or is there a reference to literature which is related? Finally, is there a good way of simulating such a thing? I've tried to simulate this via just a Poisson jump process, which I then renormalize so that $t_n=n$ but this seems rather asymmetric.

I suppose equivalently this is an interacting particle system with the above nearest neighbor correlations.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the problem a little bit and this might be totally off, but could this be related to the typical "birth-death" process?

Comment: @DonkeyKong: I apologize if I've done a bad job explaining.  The way to think about it is that it's a set of points $x_i$, say on $[0,1]$  after renormalization, where the nearest neighbor correlations are given by $f_i(t)$ which is the distribution of $x_{i+1}-x_i$.

Comment: Ohh I see, thanks. An interesting problem.